# How can I get the log file related to a particular application?

Tags: android

I want the log file for my application. How can I get the log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [tutorial on accessing the logs programmatically](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically). You can filter the items you see by using LogCat filters (e.g. to filter to one application using its tag) - here's [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat)